# Angular splash screen animation very choppy and not smooth

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an angular splash screen animation that works fine if there is nothing happening in the background but if I mimic an actual real life application the animation stutters, is choppy or sometimes just doesn't animate.

What is the best solution for this?

Here is the animation css

```
.loader {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  -webkit-animation: load4 1.3s infinite linear;
  animation: load4 1.3s infinite linear;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes load4 {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 0.2em, 2em -2em 0 0em, 3em 0 0 -1em, 2em 2em 0 -1em, 0 3em 0 -1em, -2em 2em 0 -1em, -3em 0 0 -1em, -2em -2em 0 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 0, 2em -2em 0 0.2em, 3em 0 0 0, 2em 2em 0 -1em, 0 3em 0 -1em, -2em 2em 0 -1em, -3em 0 0 -1em, -2em -2em 0 -1em;
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -0.5em, 2em -2em 0 0, 3em 0 0 0.2em, 2em 2em 0 0, 0 3em 0 -1em, -2em 2em 0 -1em, -3em 0 0 -1em, -2em -2em 0 -1em;
  }
  37.5% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -1em, 2em -2em 0 -1em, 3em 0em 0 0, 2em 2em 0 0.2em, 0 3em 0 0em, -2em 2em 0 -1em, -3em 0em 0 -1em, -2em -2em 0 -1em;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -1em, 2em -2em 0 -1em, 3em 0 0 -1em, 2em 2em 0 0em, 0 3em 0 0.2em, -2em 2em 0 0, -3em 0em 0 -1em, -2em -2em 0 -1em;
  }
  62.5% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -1em, 2em -2em 0 -1em, 3em 0 0 -1em, 2em 2em 0 -1em, 0 3em 0 0, -2em 2em 0 0.2em, -3em 0 0 0, -2em -2em 0 -1em;
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0 -1em, 2em -2em 0 -1em, 3em 0em 0 -1em, 2em 2em 0 -1em, 0 3em 0 -1em, -2em 2em 0 0, -3em 0em 0 0.2em, -2em -2em 0 0;
  }
  87.5% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0 0, 2em -2em 0 -1em, 3em 0 0 -1em, 2em 2em 0 -1em, 0 3em 0 -1em, -2em 2em 0 0, -3em 0em 0 0, -2em -2em 0 0.2em;
  }
}
@keyframes load4 {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 0.2em, 2em -2em 0 0em, 3em 0 0 -1em, 2em 2em 0 -1em, 0 3em 0 -1em, -2em 2em 0 -1em, -3em 0 0 -1em, -2em -2em 0 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 0, 2em -2em 0 0.2em, 3em 0 0 0, 2em 2em 0 -1em, 0 3em 0 -1em, -2em 2em 0 -1em, -3em 0 0 -1em, -2em -2em 0 -1em;
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -0.5em, 2em -2em 0 0, 3em 0 0 0.2em, 2em 2em 0 0, 0 3em 0 -1em, -2em 2em 0 -1em, -3em 0 0 -1em, -2em -2em 0 -1em;
  }
  37.5% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -1em, 2em -2em 0 -1em, 3em 0em 0 0, 2em 2em 0 0.2em, 0 3em 0 0em, -2em 2em 0 -1em, -3em 0em 0 -1em, -2em -2em 0 -1em;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -1em, 2em -2em 0 -1em, 3em 0 0 -1em, 2em 2em 0 0em, 0 3em 0 0.2em, -2em 2em 0 0, -3em 0em 0 -1em, -2em -2em 0 -1em;
  }
  62.5% {
    box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -1em, 2em -2em 0 -1em, 3em 0 0 -1em, 2em 2em 0 -1em, 0 3em 0 0, -2em 2em 0 0.2em, -3em 0 0 0, -2em -2em 0 -1em;
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0 -1em, 2em -2em 0 -1em, 3em 0em 0 -1em, 2em 2em 0 -1em, 0 3em 0 -1em, -2em 2em 0 0, -3em 0em 0 0.2em, -2em -2em 0 0;
  }
  87.5% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0 0, 2em -2em 0 -1em, 3em 0 0 -1em, 2em 2em 0 -1em, 0 3em 0 -1em, -2em 2em 0 0, -3em 0em 0 0, -2em -2em 0 0.2em;
  }
```

Here is a stackblitz showing the issue. The timer sets and interval where something happens in the background every second on the interval.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyo4a8-sura86?file=app%2Fdatepicker-date-class-example.ts

Comment: What do you mean by "mimic an actual real life application"? This sounds like its not in the actual production environment so you don't really know how it will function correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animating CSS `box-shadow` causes repaints every frame and is therefore NOT performant. The easiest solution is to create a pseudo-element that looks like the shadow and animate that.

Here's a great [example and background](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/) by Tobias Ahlin